# SQL error #1064 when nesting a SELECT MAX in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Please let me know why I get an error on the following SQL (I am using a MySQL database) and how to rectify it:

```
SELECT at_award_description.ad_id,
    at_award_description.ad_detail,
    at_award_description.ad_archived_date,
    a.cad_id,
    a.cad_task_completion_date
FROM at_award_description
LEFT JOIN at_cub_award_date AS a ON ((at_award_description.ad_id = a.ad_id)
    AND (a.ca_id = 37)
    AND a.cad_task_completion_date = (SELECT MAX(b.cad_task_completion_date)
                                      FROM at_cub_award_date AS b
                                      WHERE a.ca_id = b.ca_id AND a.ad_id = b.ad_id
                                     )
)
WHERE at_award_description.aw_id = 5
ORDER BY at_award_description.ad_order;
```

I broke the SQL down to ensure each part worked.

```
SELECT MAX(b.cad_task_completion_date)
FROM at_cub_award_date AS b
```

And

```
SELECT at_award_description.ad_id,
    at_award_description.ad_detail,
    at_award_description.ad_archived_date,
    a.cad_id,
    a.cad_task_completion_date
FROM at_award_description
LEFT JOIN at_cub_award_date AS a ON ((at_award_description.ad_id = a.ad_id)
    AND (a.ca_id = 37)
)
WHERE at_award_description.aw_id = 5
ORDER BY at_award_description.ad_order;
```

Each of these work on their own. When I combine them I get the following error:
Error
SQL query:
LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said:
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Regards,

Glyn

EDIT
@Barmar came up with the solution to remove the ";" at the end when testing. However, the result was not what I expected so I ended up changing this to:

```
SELECT at_award_description.ad_id, 
               at_award_description.aw_id, 
               at_award_description.ad_group, 
               at_award_description.ad_detail, 
               at_award_description.ad_start_date, 
               at_award_description.ad_archived_date,
    MAX(at_cub_award_date.cad_task_completion_date)
FROM at_award_description
LEFT JOIN at_cub_award_date ON ((at_award_description.ad_id = at_cub_award_date.ad_id)
    AND (at_cub_award_date.ca_id = 37))
WHERE at_award_description.aw_id = 5
GROUP BY at_award_description.ad_group
ORDER BY at_award_description.ad_order, at_award_description.ad_group
```

Comment: The message says the error is near `LIMIT 0, 25`. I don't see that in any of your queries.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I do not have a "LIMIT 0, 25" in my SQL, so I think this must be generated. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: MySQL doesn't generate that by itself. Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, Sorry I do not understand your request. The code I have pasted here is exactly what I am running in MySQL using phpMyAdmin. Regards, Glyn.

Comment: Ahh, you didn't mention `phpMyAdmin` in the question. Apparently it adds that to limit the number of rows it displays. Try removing the `;` at the end of the query.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, Sorry I did not know that was relevant. That did the job. However, the result was not what I expected and I ended up with the edit above. Thanks for your help. Regards, Glyn

Comment: Are you using an old version (3.4.x or previous) of phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: Hi @NicolaFerraro, I am using 4.1.14. Regards, Glyn.